# How to implement Authorization with Custom Directives in apollo with graphql-tools/utils?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I know that Apollo 2 allowed custom directives by extending the class "SchemaDirectiveVisitor." However, I am using apollo 3 and I know that the way to achieve this now is by using graphql-tools/utils and graphql-tools/schema.

In my index.js I have the following code:

```js
const serverServer = async () => {
   app.use(AuthMiddleware);

   app.use(
      cors({
         origin: 'mydomain',
      })
   );

   let schema = makeExecutableSchema({
      typeDefs: [typeDefsLibrary, typeDefsDynamicContent, userTypeDefs],
      resolvers: {
         Query,
         Mutation,
         Article,
         Blog,
         Podcast,
         SermonNotes,
         Sermon,
         // dynamic Content
         Friday,
         Thursday,
         // Post Content
         Commentary,
         Quote,
         Thought,
         UserContent_SermonNotes,
         // User Content
         User,
         All_Posts,
      },
   });

   schema = AuthorizationDirective(schema, 'auth');

   const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      context: ({ req }) => {
         const { isAuth, user } = req;
         return {
            req,
            isAuth,
            user,
         };
      },
   });

   await apolloServer.start();
   apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app: app, path: '/api' });

   app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port 4000`);
   });
};

serverServer();
```

then on my schema file I have:

```js
  directive @auth(requires: [RoleName] ) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION 
  
  enum RoleName {
    SUPERADMIN
    ADMIN
  }

   type Commentary @auth(requires: [SUPERADMIN, ADMIN]) {
      ID: ID
      USER_ID: ID
      VERSE_ID: String
      body: String
      category_tags: String
      referenced_verses: String
      verse_citation: String
      created_date: String
      posted_on: String
      creator(avatarOnly: Boolean): User
      comments(showComment: Boolean): [Commentary_Comment]
      approvals: [Commentary_Approval]
      total_count: Int
   }
```

and this is my custom directive code:

```js
const { mapSchema, getDirective, MapperKind } = require('@graphql-tools/utils');
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require('graphql');
const { ApolloError } = require('apollo-server-express');
//const { logging } = require('../../helpers');

module.exports.AuthorizationDirective = (schema, directiveName) => {
   return mapSchema(schema, {
      [MapperKind.FIELD]: (fieldConfig, _fieldName, typeName) => {
         const authDirective = getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName);
         console.log('auth Directive line 10: ', authDirective);
         if (authDirective && authDirective.length) {
            const requiredRoles = authDirective[0].requires;

            if (requiredRoles && requiredRoles.length) {
               const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = fieldConfig;
               fieldConfig.resolve = function (source, args, context, info) {
                  if (requiredRoles.includes('PUBLIC')) {
                     console.log(
                        `==> ${context.code || 'ANONYMOUS'} ACCESSING PUBLIC RESOLVER: ${
                           info.fieldName
                        }`
                     );
                     //logging(context, info.fieldName, args);

                     return resolve(source, args, context, info);
                  }

                  if (!requiredRoles.includes(context.code)) {
                     throw new ApolloError('NOT AUTHORIZED', 'NO_AUTH');
                  }
                  console.log(`==> ${context.code} ACCESSING PRIVATE RESOLVER: ${info.fieldName}`);
                  //logging(context, info.fieldName, args);

                  return resolve(source, args, context, info);
               };

               return fieldConfig;
            }
         }
      },
   });
};
```

But is not working. It seems like it is not even calling the Custom Directive. As you see I have a "console.log('auth Directive line 10: ', authDirective);" on my schema directive function that return "undefined."

I know this post is so ling but I hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the code worked for me**

**I have used [MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: not [MapperKind.FIELD]:**

I have referred this from @graphql-tools ->
https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives#enforcing-access-permissions

`
const { mapSchema, getDirective, MapperKind } = require('@graphql-tools/utils');
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require('graphql');

const HasRoleDirective = (schema, directiveName) => {
return mapSchema(schema, {

```
// Executes once for each object field in the schems
[MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: (fieldConfig, _fieldName, typeName) => {

  // Check whether this field has the specified directive
  const authDirective = getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName);

  if (authDirective && authDirective.length) {
    const requiredRoles = authDirective[0].requires;
    // console.log("requiredRoles: ", requiredRoles);

    if (requiredRoles && requiredRoles.length) {
      // Get this field's original resolver
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = fieldConfig;

      // Replace the original resolver with function that "first" calls 
      fieldConfig.resolve = function (source, args, context, info) {
        // console.log("Context Directive:  ", context);
        const { currentUser } = context;
        if(!currentUser) throw new Error("Not Authenticated");

        const { type } = currentUser['userInfo']
        const isAuthorized = hasRole(type, requiredRoles);
        if(!isAuthorized) throw new Error("You Have Not Enough Permissions!")

        //logging(context, info.fieldName, args);
        return resolve(source, args, context, info);
      };
      return fieldConfig;
    }
  }
}
```

})
}
`